# addition of three columns based on filtering and user input using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, addition

I have a data frame.It is one intermediate csv file .
It has following data.

```
 sv1   val1    sv2    val2    sv3   val3
   2     0.2     4      0.6      8     0.3
   2     0.1     6      0.1      8     0.11
   2     0.12    6      -0.3     8     0.2
   5     0       4      1.6      8     0.7
   2     0.34    6      2.3      8     0.12
   ...   ....   ...     ....    ...   .....
```

Aim:Addition of val1+val2+val3 if sv1,sv2,sv3 does not contain 5.
If any svs column(say sv1) contain 5 then addition would be val2+val3

```
# Attempt
import pandas as pd
names=['sv1','sv2','sv3','val1','val2','val3']
df=pd.read_csv('Myfile.csv',names=names)
discard_id=int(raw_input('enter the number to discard')

add_result=df.loc[['sv1','sv2','sv3']!=discard_id]
           .....
          perform  addition
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compare all values by `discard_id` and get [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for at least one `True` per row. Then `sum` columns by `subset`s and add to new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
discard_id = 5

m = (df[['sv1','sv2','sv3']] == discard_id).any(axis=1)
sum1 = df[['val1','val2','val3']].sum(axis=1)
sum2 = df[['val2','val3']].sum(axis=1)

df['new'] = np.where(m, sum2, sum1)

print (df)
   sv1  val1  sv2  val2  sv3  val3   new
0    2  0.20    4   0.6    8  0.30  1.10
1    2  0.10    6   0.1    8  0.11  0.31
2    2  0.12    6  -0.3    8  0.20  0.02
3    5  0.00    4   1.6    8  0.70  2.30
4    2  0.34    6   2.3    8  0.12  2.76
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print (sum1)
0    1.10
1    0.31
2    0.02
3    2.30
4    2.76
dtype: float64

print (sum2)
0    0.90
1    0.21
2   -0.10
3    2.30
4    2.42
dtype: float64
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [312]: %%timeit
     ...: m = (df[['sv1','sv2','sv3']] == discard_id).any(axis=1)
     ...: sum1 = df[['val1','val2','val3']].sum(axis=1)
     ...: sum2 = df[['val2','val3']].sum(axis=1)
     ...: df['new'] = np.where(m, sum2, sum1)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.77 ms per loop

#jp_data_analysis's solution
In [313]: %%timeit
     ...: df['sum'] = df.apply(summer, axis=1, num=5)
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 287 ms per loop
```

Comment: @ jezrael . can not we use df.loc[' '] instead of only df['paramter']?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `print (df.loc[:, ['paramter', 'paramter1']])` is same as `print (df[['paramter', 'paramter1']])` if want select columns names. If want select index values need `print (df.loc[[0, 1]])` and for one idex value - `print (df.loc[0])`.

Comment: @ jezrael . So I can write m = (df.loc[:,['sv1','sv2','sv3']] == discard_id).any(axis=1)? in previous example

Comment: @Poka - yes, exactly. It is same.

Comment: @ jezrael. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
def summer(row, num):
    return sum(i for i, j in zip([row['val1'], row['val2'], row['val3']],
                                 [row['sv1'], row['sv2'], row['sv3']]) if j!=num)

df['sum'] = df.apply(summer, axis=1, num=5)
```

Comment: I add timings in my answer, I think in pandas is the best avoid loops - `apply` + `list comprehension`s if exist vectorized solutions.

Comment: @jezrael. I agree with you and upvoted your answer. But, for smaller data sets, I would argue that mine is preferable for readability  :).

Comment: Thank you. In past in some time I used list comprehensions more, but Jeff (one of main developer of pandas ) add comment after one my solution for avoid it. So I stop it. If data contains some lists or sets, then `list comprehension` is good choice ;) Only friend comment, because you like list comprehensions a lot :)

Comment: technically this is a generator compression, no lists being created here :). but I accept your general point.

Comment: ya, my problem is I learn first pandas and then python, so bad wording ;) Good luck!